# Spring boot Rest API, Angular 6 SSO Social login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, angular6, single-sign-on

I'm building a Angular 6 front-end and Spring boot based REST api. Angular app is going to be hosted separately behind a nginx. I want to implement spring security in order to secure REST apis. As per my understanding I need to two following things.

- Spring security to authenticate API calls for valid tokens and respond 403 if not
- Angular library in order to redirect user to google login and maintain access/refresh tokens, pass access token for api calls in headers and refresh access token if backend respond with 403.

I'm not quite sure whether the authenticate request go via spring backend or directly to google.

I have been searching for a good tutorial for sometime but didn't find one matching my requirement( most are html pages hosted within spring ). So please correct if my understanding on how to do this is wrong and share if there are tutorials.